# Atom Snap Install Freezing

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, freeze, snap, atom

Everytime I try to install Atom on my Ubuntu 16.04.3 machine as a snap app the terminal freezes at a point after the core and Atom app have downloaded and begun installing.

The computer does not accept any keyboard or mouse input. No error is shown on the terminal display.

I tried installing Atom by typing in the command `sudo snap install --classic atom` as stated in the official documentation [here](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/05/11/atom-is-now-available-as-a-snap-for-ubuntu/).

I am unable to take a screenshot of the terminal freezing as the computer does not accept any keyboard input and the [REISUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes) option does not work. I am forced to hold down the power button and restart the computer (after giving it half an hour to see if it may unfreeze).

After restarting the computer first in recovery mode and then on to normal mode, I can see that the snap has not installed. 
[snap list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBpj6.png)

I tried the installation three times and it freezes repeatedly at the same point when it begins installing.

How do I install Atom as a snap? Will installing it from the Ubuntu Software centre be any different?

Comment: Can you open another terminal, and in it run ```dmesg -Tw``` (to tail the syslog) and try again. Perhaps you will see some output in the syslog before the system freezes? Also, can you ```snap version``` to let us know what version of the snapd package you have?

Comment: Thanks to your line of code from the documentation I could install it. On my computer neither the deb downloaded from Atom nor the snap via Ubuntu Software where installing.

Comment: @RamonSuarez can you write up what you did as an answer and accept it please? :)

Comment: Written @Ads20000 , I'm not the OP so I don't think I can accept it.

Comment: @RamonSuarez ah yeah sorry I didn't notice that. Thanks for writing it :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your line of code from the documentation I could install it. On my computer neither the deb downloaded from Atom nor the snap via Ubuntu Software where installing.

```
sudo snap install --classic atom
```

And it also has the advantage that it [autoupdates Atom](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/05/11/atom-is-now-available-as-a-snap-for-ubuntu/).